# NoMethodError for "calculations" when using has_one (works with has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use `InheritedResources` in my new rails project. I have 2 model: `district` and `calculation`. I want use rails association, for this, when I use `has_many` all of things are right, but when I use `has_one` I get below error:

```
Started GET "/districts/17/calculations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-10 11:29:07 +0
430
Processing by CalculationsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"district_id"=>"17"}
  District Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "districts".* FROM "districts"  WHERE "district
s"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `calculations' for #<District:0x0000000545d968>)
```

`districts_controller.rb`:

```
class DistrictsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json

  def district_params
    params.require(:district).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

`district.rb`:

```
class District < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calculation, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

`calculations_controller.rb`:

```
class CalculationsController < InheritedResources::Base

  belongs_to :district
  respond_to :json

  def calculation_params
    params.require(:calculation).permit(:district_id, :price)
  end

end
```

`calculation.rb`:

```
class Calculation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :district
end
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :districts, :defaults => {format: :json} do
    resources :calculations, :defaults => {format: :json}
  end
```

`rake routes`:

```
district_calculations GET    /districts/:district_id/calculations(.:format) calculations#index {:format=>:json}
                          POST   /districts/:district_id/calculations(.:format) calculations#create {:format=>:json}
 new_district_calculation GET    /districts/:district_id/calculations/new(.:format)      calculations#new {:format=>:json}
```

Problem is fixed when I use `has_many` association and work correctly, but when I use `has_one`, I get this error. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `has_one :calculation` there is a single *calculation*, not many *calculations*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to `district.calculation`, rather than `district.calculations`.

Things work when you use a has_many calculation because district.calculations calls all of the (one or more) calculations that reference that district. Rails expects a plural form of calculation for a has_many association.

This breaks when you change the association to a has_one, because when District has_one calculation, you can never reference multiple calculations. Rails is smart enough to know this, and requires the singular .calculation method for a has_one association.